# If a 32 bit address processor can access 4GB how does this processor deal with hard disk of size 500 Gb?

Tags: operating-system

A 32-bit register can store 232 different values. The signed range of integer values that can be stored in 32 bits is -2,147,483,648 through 2,147,483,647 (unsigned: 0 through 4,294,967,295). Hence, a processor with 32-bit memory addresses can directly access 4 GiB of byte-addressable memory. so how this kind of processor deal with disk of size more than 4 gb?

Comment: Disks aren't part of main memory. They're peripherals, accessed through I/O buses. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bus_(computing)

Comment: @Mat That was possibly the least useful comment that could have been made.

Answer (score 1):

> Hence, a processor with 32-bit memory addresses can directly access 4 GiB of byte-addressable memory. so how this kind of processor deal with disk of size more than 4 gb?

For disks; typically they're not byte addressable and the smallest amount that can be read or written (the block size) is 512 bytes or larger (maybe 4096 bytes). Block numbers may also be larger than 32 bits (e.g. maybe 48 bit block numbers).

With 512-byte blocks and 48 bit block numbers (which was common in the late 1990s; for ATA and SATA, etc) you'd end up with a maximum disk size of 134217728 GiB.

Of course the CPU probably (see note) can't directly access any of the data on disk. Software (file system) has to ask a device driver to fetch the block/s it wants, and device driver asks hardware (disk controller) to copy data between disk and memory. Depending on OS; this software interface (used by file system to ask device driver to read or write blocks) most likely uses 64-bit block numbers (e.g. two 32-bit registers joined together).

Note: More recently, the possibility of using non-volatile RAM (e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3D_XPoint ) as storage changed things (it is byte addressable and does use physical addresses); but modern hardware is all "64-bit" (with physical addresses that may be 48 bits or larger in practice) so even though the theoretical limit is much smaller it's still large enough in practice (e.g. maybe 200000 GiB).

Answer (score 0):

On x86-64, the main CPU architecture of most desktop computers, an interface is standardized in the AHCI (Advanced Host Controller Interface). The computer accesses the hard-disk using this interface which is, in practice, a PCI-Express device compliant with the PCI-Express specification.

With PCI, the CPU has a memory controller which will write to the PCI devices registers instead of RAM when writing to some portions of RAM. Software (the operating-system) will write in uncached RAM and it will instead write to the registers of the PCI device. This way it can tell the devices, including an AHCI, to do some operations like a DMA operation from the hard-disk to RAM and vice-versa.

I didn't read the specification in full but the specification probably holds 64 bits registers that can be written as 2 32 bits words. More often, software will write to the lower part of the register then to the higher part of the register. This allows any 32 bits computers to still be able to interact with AHCI. On a 64 bits computer, the registers will be written as one 64 bits write.

A 32 bits computer is thus still able to trigger DMA writes to some portions of the hard-disk which are much higher than 4GB.